# Hosting google custom engine annotations

Tags: xml, annotations, google-custom-search

I'm trying to host annotations online.

Adding this include.xml to Google Custom search account CSE annotations:

```
<GoogleCustomizations>
  <Include type="Annotations" href="http://mywebsite.m/dynamic-annotations.xml" /> 
</GoogleCustomizations>
```

My dynamic-annotations.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
</Annotations>
      <Annotation about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*">
        <Label name="_cse_l98hzi05fja" />
      </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

Search results does not appears from Wikipedia. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `</Annotations>` needs less /.

```
 <Annotations>
    blah  
 </Annotations>
```

should work, give that a go (hoping you've fixed this since August though)